# previously present folder is getting deleted

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3

I am installing a Wix msi. It adds folders and files to an already existing folder installed by another application. When i uninstall the msi, it deletes the existing folder. Tried using shared="yes". The problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to add the same set of files as installed by other Application into that folder (but with different Guid), Uninstalling one would remove all the files.